# How to exact folder name from an Excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of file paths thousands of rows of Excel cells and I am trying to extract a specific part of path which is the parent folder of the file.

IE:

```
/Users/USER/share/photos/slide/box/TEXT TO EXTRACT IS HERE/file.jpg
```

In every case, I am trying to get the last folder name before the .jpg which is where I put the text "TEXT TO EXTRACT IS HERE" in the example. Is this possible in Excel?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a mouthful, but it works with any number of "/" signs in the path:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1))-1)
```

Comment: You are amazing! That worked!!